# Plugin to rename a build in jenkins using build parameter variables

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin to rename a build in Jenkins based on a variable in "Parameterised build"? I tried Build+Name+Setter+Plugin, but it has note in the help section that says

> Blockquote
>   ${ENV,var="VARIABLENAME"}
>   Expands to an environment variable (specified here as VARIABLENAME) from the build environment. Note that this does not include any variables set by the build scripts themselves, only those set by Jenkins and other plugins.

So the format #$jiraissue-${BUILD_NUMBER} (Where jiraissue is parameter passed to the build) didn't work when I tried it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Pro in Jenkins CI but this might be something of your interest.

[Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks. I was using this plugin but didn't put in the format right. All good.

Answer (score 1):

This worked :)

## ${BUILD_NUMBER}-${ENV,var="jiraissue"}